# Compress a folder with tar?

Tags: linux, backup, tar

I'm trying to compress a folder (`/var/www/`) to `~/www_backups/$time.tar` where `$time` is the current date.

This is what I have:

```
cd /var/www && sudo tar -czf ~/www_backups $time"
```

I am completely lost and I've been at this for hours now. Not sure if `-czf` is correct. I simply want to copy all of the content in `/var/www` into a `$time.tar` file, and I want to maintain the file permissions for all of the files. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: you need a " on the other side of `$time` as well.

Answer (score 613, accepted):

To `tar` and `gzip` a folder, the syntax is:

```
tar czf name_of_archive_file.tar.gz name_of_directory_to_tar
```

Adding `-` before the options (`czf`) is optional with `tar`. The effect of `czf` is as follows:

- `c` — create an archive file (as opposed to extract, which is `x`)
- `f` — filename of the archive file
- `z` — filter archive through `gzip` (remove this option to create a `.tar` file)

If you want to `tar` the current directory, use `.` to designate that.

To construct filenames dynamically, use the `date` utility (look at its man page for the available format options). For example:

```
cd /var/www &&
tar czf ~/www_backups/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).tar.gz .
```

This will create a file named something like `20120902-185558.tar.gz`.

On Linux, chances are your `tar` also supports BZip2 compression with the `j` rather than `z` option. And possibly others. Check the man page on your local system.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I have one tiny issue though. After creating a tar file of /var/www, it is placed within /var/www directories in the tar file. Here's the code i'm using now  `sudo tar -czf ~/www_backups/$time.tar /var/www/"` Imagine i have a  file called test.txt inside /var/www. After making a tar copy of the file, when i extract it it will be placed inside /var/www directories. Does that make sense? I hope it does, kinda hard to explain. I will check for BZip2 support, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: That's why you first `cd` to the directory you want to package, then `tar cf file.tar .` - that last `.` instead of specifying the full path will make the paths inside the archive relative to the current directory. You could also use the  `-C` option for tar (look at the man page).

Comment: Yup, that worked much better. Thanks a bunch, appreciate it!

Comment: @Qwertylicious `-f` (from man page) `Read the archive from or write the archive to the specified file.The filename can be - for standard input or standard output.`

Comment: With recent versions of tar the uppercase `J` (instead of the `z`) will use the [xz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz) LZMA2 compression.

Comment: Why sudo? If the current user has read access to the www directory, it's very likely that it also has read access to everything else.

Comment: `sudo` was in the question, didn't change or question that. Having the backup target directory restricted to root isn't a bad idea though.

Comment: Got thrown off by a message saying `Can't add archive to itself` but this worked. Would prefer to see this answer the question with more brevity.

Comment: The version I personally prefer to archive is `tar -cvpf archive_name.tar directory_to_tar/`

And to unpack, I prefer the flags `tar --same-owner -xvf archive_to_unpack.tar`

Answer (score 36):

**Examples for Most Common Compression Algorithms**

The question title for this is simply "Compress a folder with tar?" Since this title is very general, but the question and answer are much more specific, and due to the very large number of views this question has attracted, I felt it would be beneficial to add an up-to-date list of examples of both archiving/compressing and extracting/uncompressing, with various commonly used compression algorithms.

These have been tested with Ubuntu 18.04.4. They are very simple for general use, but could easily be integrated into the OP's more specific question contents using the the techniques in the accepted answer and helpful comments above.

One thing to note for the more general audience is that `tar` will not add the necessary extensions (like `.tar.gz`) automatically - the user has to explicitly add those, as seen in the commands below:

```
# 1: tar (create uncompressed archive) all files and directories in the current working directory recursively into an uncompressed tarball
tar cvf filename.tar *

# 2: Untar (extract uncompressed archive) all files and directories in an uncompressed tarball recursively into the current working directory
tar xvf filename.tar

# 3: tar (create gzipped archive) all files and directories in the current working directory recursively into a tarball compressed with gzip
tar cvzf filename.tar.gz *

# 4: Untar (extract gzipped archive) all files and directories in a tarball compressed with gzip recursively into the current working directory
tar xvf filename.tar.gz # Note: same options as 2 above

# 5: tar (create bzip2'ed archive) all files and directories in the current working directory recursively into a tarball compressed with bzip2
tar cvjf filename.tar.bz2 * # Note: little 'j' in options

# 6: Untar (extract bzip2'ed archive) all files and directories in an tarball compressed with bzip2 recursively into the current working directory
tar xvf filename.tar.bz2 # Note: same options as 2 and 4 above

# 7: tar (create xz'ed archive) all files and directories in the current working directory recursively into a tarball compressed with xz
tar cvJf filename.tar.xz * # Note: capital 'J' in options

# 8: Untar (extract xz'ed archive) all files and directories in an tarball compressed with xz recursively into the current working directory
tar xvf filename.tar.xz # Note: same options as 2, 4, and 6 above
```

See the tar [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) (best to use `man tar` on your specific machine) for further details. Below I summarize the options used above directly from the man page:

> -c, --create
>       create a new archive
>
> -x, --extract, --get
>       extract files from an archive
>
> -v, --verbose
>       verbosely list files processed
>
> -z, --gzip
>       filter the archive through gzip
>
> -j, --bzip2
>       filter the archive through bzip2
>
> -J, --xz
>       filter the archive through xz
>
> -f, --file=ARCHIVE
>       use archive file or device ARCHIVE

No need to add the `-` in front of the combined options, or the `=` sign between the `f` option and the filename.

I got all this from my recent [article](https://www.xitalogy.com/linux-unix/2020/02/06/using-tar-to-archive-extract-compress-uncompress-files.html), which will be expanded further into a much more comprehensive article as I have time to work on it.