# How to compress the directory and its contents

Tags: ksh, aix, compression

How do I compress a directory and its contents in `ksh` on `AIX`

for a file I do `compress filename`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compress a folder with tar?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46969/56041)

Answer (score 5):

`tar cjf <your-name-in-specific-path> <your-directory-path>`

```
c: Create              
j: Use bzip2 for compression            
f: Save it to given file name
```

**NOTE:** If your tar version doesn't have these options you can follow the below instruction:

1. `tar cf <your-name-in-specific-path> <your-directory-path>`
2. `gzip <your-name-in-specific-path>`

**NOTE:** You can compress your file with other tools like `bzip2`, `xz` and so on.

Comment: once you have tar and compressed the directory, you'll have to delete it in order to reclaim space, this might not be what you wanted.

Comment: @Mat, Thanks for your notice... I edited my post.

Comment: AIX doesn't come with bzip2 by default either.

Answer (score 3):

A directory cannot be compressed, because a directory is not a plain file.  It is a pointer to a container of a set of files.

You can `tar` a directory and its contents into a single file and compress that file.  Or you can `cd` into the directory and compress each individual file.

Answer (score 3):

Tar in AIX by default does not support compression. You will need to incorporate with gzip command to have it tar and compress at the same time.

```
$ tar cvf test.tar test                      # pure tar only
$ tar cvf - test | gzip > test.tar.gz        # tar and compress together
```

To uncompress and untar as well :

```
$ gunzip -c test.tar.gz | tar tvf -           # list compress files
$ gunzip -c test.tar.gz | tar xvf -           # decompress files
```